# What is wrong with いきなり涼しくなった

Tags: word-usage

While talking about the weather, I said:

> ✖️　いきなり涼しくなった

My interlocutor corrected me:

> ◯　急に涼しくなった

I would like to understand what makes いきなり inappropriate to avoid making the same kind of mistake again.

I have found that the following sentences are correct even though they look quite similar to 「涼しくなった」 to me:

> ◯　いきなり揺れた。　（今朝起きた地震についてなど）
>
> ◯　車を運転していたら、いきなりタイヤが破裂した。
>
> ◯　いきなりトイレが使えなくなった。

I have read [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14020/), but it did not help me understand when *not* to use いきなり.

Comment: It's best to ask these questions of the people who make the correction on the spot... It may be as simple as they personally say it one way more than the other.

Comment: I asked, but I did not get anything more than that いきなり is not something she would say in this context (of discussing the weather).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

いきなり is not terribly wrong, but いきなり tends to express a truly instant event that occurs all of a sudden. If I understand the context correctly, you are describing a phenomenon that progresses over a few days, so 急に sounds more natural. But if you have unexpectedly entered a cold room, saying いきなり涼しくなった is equally natural.

As the linked question says, いきなり also carries the nuance of subjective unexpectedness or mental unpreparedness, but this difference is not important now.

Comment: In addition to what @naruto says, I have the feeling that いきなり tends to be used slightly more often for negative things, since for instance いきなり寒くなった sounds more natural to me. This being said, as naruto points out, いきなり涼しくなった is really not so wrong (as a matter of fact, as a native speaker I might say the same and I had to think a bit to know why it was considered as wrong).